# Passing easing behaviors between elements, jQueryUI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an object `accordionOptions` which mediates the behavior of an accordion object
on my page. It looks like:

```
 var accordionOptions = {
                icons: {
                    header: 'ui-icon-circle-arrows-e',
                    activeHeader: 'ui-icon-notice'
                },
                animate: {
                    easing: 'easeOutBounce',
                    duration: 1000
                }
            }
```

I'm using that object to determine the behavior of my accordion like so:

```
 $('#accordion1').accordion({
                icons: accordionOptions.icons,
                animate: accordionOptions.animate
            });
```

I have an anchor tag on my page that when clicked I intend for it to have the same animation as the accordion when a new panel is clicked:

```
$('#btnChange').click(function () {
                $('#test').animate({

                    easing: accordionOptions.animate.easing
                });
            });
```

You can see in the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/C6Eax/) this doesn't work.  I've tried several things, all were non-successes.  How can I attach my desired behavior to the `test` div using my `accordionOptions` argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using easing for `.animate` is slightly different than for `.accordion` -- you need to pass the duration and easing separately from what should be animated. You should set a height or whatever property it should animate.

```
$('#test').animate({ height: 100 }, accordionOptions.animate.duration, accordionOptions.animate.easing);
```

Or shorter syntax similar to how you were originally doing it:

```
$('#test').animate({ height: 100 }, accordionOptions.animate);
```

**Updated fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/C6Eax/1/

Comment: You can also pass easing and duration in the same object if you like, it just needs to be the second parameter (since the first mentions which properties to animate).

Comment: I can see now that I neglected to animation the y axis placement of the test element so there's no way it would've worked, even if I had passed the correct properties.

Comment: @wootscootinboogie exactly, pretty crucial as jQuery is awesome but yet to read our minds ;)